# Successfully Call history.pushState() from Angular Without Inifinite Digest?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Is there a way to call `history.pushState()` without angular going into an infinite digest loop?

I'm trying to migrate my app from backend routing to frontend routing and all the stackoverflow posts/google resources don't seem to have an answer.

Comment: I'm too stuck with this problem.. what is the reason this happens? do you know?

Answer (score 14):

This is what we do in an Angular 1.2.16 app based on this github comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3924#issuecomment-48592773

```
$location.url(myNewUrl);
$location.replace();
$window.history.pushState(null, 'any', $location.absUrl());
```

This code is part of a controller.
I'm using it to add a query param to the url without wanting to reload the page. It works in our case.

Answer (score 11):

I recently encountered a variation of this problem myself and none of the answers here worked for me in isolation. `history.pushState` was defined, but only worked if called from the console. I was able to come up with a solution by consolidating a few of the answers here. Here is the code I used to solve this problem:

```
// Configure $locationProvider html5Mode
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false, rewriteLinks: false });
}]);

// In controller
$window.history.pushState(null, 'Page Title', '/some_new_url');
```

I'm running Angular 1.5.5.

Answer (score 5):

Use the rewriteLinks option on the $locationProvider html5Mode object:

```
    pageModule.config(function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false,
            rewriteLinks: false
        });
    });
```

Afterwards, you should be able to use the $location service properly, such as:

```
    this.$location.path("/mynewpath");
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to come up with a solution that works with angular 1.2.15.

The gist of it is to add a `target` attribute to each link and then use the `$location` service to change the location.

Based on the current angular code, anchor tags that have a target attribute are ignored (note that this solution may eventually break).

To do this, ensure this javascript runs *before* angular:

```
// prevent angular from taking over link clicks until we have frontend routing
$(document.documentElement).on("click","a",function(event) {
  var elem = $(this), target = elem.attr("target");
  if(!target) {
    elem.attr("target","_self");
    setTimeout(function() {
      elem.removeAttr("target");
    });
  }
});
```

After that, configure your location provider to use html5mode:

```
  angular.module("App", ["App.controllers"]).config([
    "$locationProvider", function($locationProvider) {
      if (history.pushState) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
      }
    }
  ]);
```

Now, in your controller, inject the location service and use it normally:

```
angular.module("App.controllers",[]).controllers("SomeController", ["$scope", "$location", function($scope,$location){
    $scope.updateLocation = function() {
      if (history.pushState) {
        $location.path("/new/path/here");
      }
    };
  }]);
```