# adding history to browser from angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using `angularjs` and `ui-router`. I have a page where i search certain content and show/hide some sections. I want to add history to browser, so that when user clicks on back. He can go to previous page where he was. How do i handle this requirement.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/27740265/2686163

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Successfully Call history.pushState() from Angular Without Inifinite Digest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914228/successfully-call-history-pushstate-from-angular-without-inifinite-digest)