# Change Browser URL without actually loading anything on the UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hash, url-routing

I have seen a lot of questions related to this where actually user wanted to change the URL (I want to change Hash) without reloading the page. But for my case, none of them seems to be working.

First here is my requirement:
A user selects some filters on the UI and data refreshes automatically. I want my URL Hash to change along with that without reloading any content of the UI.

I tried following options available on Stack Overflow:

1. Change the document hash to the new hash URL:

document.location.hash = new_hash_value;

2. Manipulate the Browser History:

   window.history.replaceState('test', 'title' , new_url);

But in both of the cases, page actually reloads (Though it doesn't reloads the data) due to this, for every selection in the drop down filter, it closes the filter options.

Can any one please help me here, how I can trick the browser to change the URL only without doing this.

(NS: Itried passing parameter reload: true, but that also do not seems to be working.)

Comment: Why is AngularJS taged here?

Comment: because the problem is on angularJs.My whole app is in Angularjs

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered before i believe.

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "PageTitle", "/url");
```

For more check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: I have already tried this option, but it seems to be laoding some of the elements and it closes the fitler dropdown

Comment: check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914228/successfully-call-history-pushstate-from-angular-without-inifinite-digest